# Error in solving differential equation $x^2y' = y\ln y - y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the problem $x^2y' = y\ln y - y'$ and found an answer but it doesn't match the back of the book.

My work:

Equation simplifies to $$\frac{1}{y\ln y}dy = \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$

Integrating both sides yields $\ln(\ln y) + c_1 = \arctan(x) + c_2$

Isolating $y$ gives $y(x) = e^{\exp({\arctan(x) + c})}$

However the back of the book gives the answer of $y(x) = e^{D\exp{\arctan(x)}}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you didn't dude

Comment: @SakethMalyala Actually they did, since $e^c$ is always positive while one wants every real $D$, positive or negative or zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{e^{\tan^{~~-1}~(x)+C}} ~~= e^{e^Ce^{\tan^{~~-1}~(x)}} = e^{De^{\tan^{~~-1}~(x)}} $$

Comment: Skirts the problem, since $e^c$ is always positive while one wants every real $D$, positive or negative or zero. (And three upvoters do not really read what they vote on, apparently.)